# SQL Server: How to add values to a table from an other table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery, sql-insert

I´m new to SQL and very mutch in need for help. I have two tables: Fact_Hours and DatePeriod.
I need to insert values to column YYYYMM in Fact_Hours table. Values come from DatePeriod table.
Here is the code I came up with but it´s not working. I get multiple errors.

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Fact_Hours]([YYYYMM])
 VALUES (SELECT [YYYYMM]
            FROM [dbo].[DatePeriod] d
            WHERE [dbo].[Fact_Hours].[CDate] = d.[Date])
```

The correct YYYYMM value is the one that has the same Date as CDate from Fact_Hours table in the same row.

I would really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

This is a common error. [INSERT INTO with SELECT](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp) doesn't require the VALUES keyword

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Fact_Hours]([YYYYMM])
SELECT [YYYYMM]
            FROM [dbo].[DatePeriod] d
            WHERE [dbo].[Fact_Hours].[CDate] = d.[Date]
```

However the SELECT query need to join the Fact_Hours table, but we don't know on which field(s) we could establish the relationship between the two tables.

Here an EXAMPLE supposing that there is a column in both tables that could be used for joins named `NameOfKeyColumn`

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Fact_Hours]([YYYYMM])
SELECT [YYYYMM]
FROM [dbo].[DatePeriod] d INNER JOIN [dbo].[Fact_Hours] f
     ON f.NameOfKeyColumn = d.NameOfKeyColumn
WHERE [dbo].[Fact_Hours].[CDate] = d.[Date]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I tryed your way and I get the error message The multi-part identifier "dbo.Fact_Hours.CDate" could not be bound.

Comment: This is because you need to join the Fact_Hours table in the select

Comment: And how do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[Fact_Hours]([YYYYMM])
    SELECT [YYYYMM]
    FROM [dbo].[DatePeriod] dp INNER JOIN [dbo].[Fact_Hours] fh
    ON fh.[CDate] = dp.[Date]
```